# Custom Button not setting record type

Tags: custom-button

I have a custom button on Object A where it creates record for Object B (No relationship btn objects). The button works fine except it doesn't sets the record type, what iam doing wrong.

/a02/e?retURL=%2F{!A__c.Id}& aid = {!A__c.Id} & 
RecordType=01240000000M828&
00N40000002Hvox="Active"&
00N40000003BOiQ={!A__c.Name}&
00N40000002HvWZ="CRB"

Comment: Try the below code /a02/e?retURL=%2F{!A__c.Id}& aid = {!A__c.Id} & RecordTypeId='01240000000M828'& 00N40000002Hvox="Active"& 00N40000003BOiQ={!A__c.Name}& 00N40000002HvWZ="CRB"

Comment: I even tried that but doesn't works

Comment: You might want to consider creating a publisher action and using that instead.

Comment: @crmprogdev how do we use Publisher action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For custom button's I would recommend using the following formatting in order to better sort and understand what is being passed. This is an example for a new case:

```
/500/e?
retURL={!Case.Id}
&RecordType=012600000005Iko
&ent=Case
&cas4={!Case.Account}
&cas4_lkid={!Case.AccountId}
```

The other thing to make sure is that you do not have any spaces in your URL code.

As a follow-up to the comment below I created this JS button and it seems to work (just POC):

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/30.0/connection.js")} 
var Status = '{!Case.Status}'; 
if(Status == "New") {window.location = "/500/e?retURL={!Case.Id}&RecordType=012C0000000I8IL&ent=Case"}
else if(Status == "Closed") {window.location = "/500/e?retURL={!Case.Id}&RecordType=012C0000000I8IL&ent=Case"}
```

I would check to make sure you need those %2f forward slashes in the URL.

Comment: Thank you It worked. Is it possible to update a field based on the status of a record? I need to pass the above values only if status is "New" for a record in Object A if status is Working then i need to pass different values, is it possible? i guess this can be done through java script but can you throw some light?

Comment: My recommendation for that is to use a hidden formula field that does the logic evaluation and creates the URL based on that logic. Let me know if that makes sense and if not I can put together an example.

Comment: @ eric clay how would we pass the formula into url , shouldn't the java script button would be easy if we use IF statements?

Comment: Getting error "invalid regular expression flag e"                  If({!ELA__c.Status__c} = "Active")
{window.location = /a02/e?
retURL=%2F{!ELA__c.Id}
&RecordType=01240000000M83B
&00N40000002Hvox="ELA"
&00N40000003BOiQ={!ELA__c.Name}
&00N40000002HvWZ="IRB"
}
Else if({!ELA__c.Status__c} = "Inactive")
{window.location = /a02/e?
retURL=%2F{!ELA__c.Id}
&RecordType=01240000000M83B
&00N40000002Hvox="BLA"
&00N40000003BOiQ={!ELA__c.Name}
&00N40000002HvWZ="CRB"
}

Comment: I am assuming the button "Content type" is "URL".

Comment: No it's Java script. I slightly modified it but still same error  {!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/30.0/connection.js")}

var Status = '{!ELA__c.Status__c}';

if(Status == "Active")
{window.location = /a02/e?
retURL=%2F{!ELA__c.Id}
&RecordType=01240000000M83B
&00N40000002Hvox="ELA"
&00N40000003BOiQ={!ELA__c.Name}
&00N40000002HvWZ="IRB"
}
else if(Status = "Inactive")
{window.location = /a02/e?
retURL=%2F{!ELA__c.Id}
&RecordType=01240000000M83B
&00N40000002Hvox="BLA"
&00N40000003BOiQ={!ELA__c.Name}
&00N40000002HvWZ="CRB"
}

Comment: If you're still having issues update your question with the latest code formatted so I can see how you have it. I've updated my original response with a quick and dirty copy of the code you had below with the fields switched around just to get it working, it seemed to work with no errors.

Comment: @ Eric clay I have modified it but iam getting this error "missing ; before statement". Here is what i have so far {!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/30.0/connection.js")}

var Status = '{!ELA__c.Status__c}';

if(Status == "Active") {window.location = "/a02/e?retURL={!ELA__c.Id}&RecordType=01240000000M83B&00N40000002Hvox="ELA"&00N40000003BOiQ={!ELA__c.Name}&00N40000002HvWZ="IRB""}
else if(Status == "Inactive"){window.location = "/a02/e?retURL={!ELA__c.Id}&RecordType=01240000000M83B&00N40000002Hvox="BLA"&00N40000003BOiQ={!ELA__c.Name}&00N40000002HvWZ="CRB""}

Answer (score 1):

The best place to learn about Global Publisher Actions, which will do what you desire, is by referring to the "Introducing Publisher Actions" Section of Chapter 8 in the [Force.com Platform Fundamentals Workbook](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/fundamentals/salesforce_creating_on_demand_apps.pdf).

Comment: But what's wrong with my code?